# How can I use os.walk or any other alternative to traverse folders recursively by the natural name order?

Tags: python, directory

In python if I iterate all the folders by os.walk recursievely to find any filr with the defined extension. this is my present code;

```
def get_data_paths(root_path, ext = '*.jpg'):
    import os
    import fnmatch
    matches = []
    classes = []
    class_names = []
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(root_path):
      for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, ext):
          matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
          class_name =  os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(os.path.join(root, filename)))
          if class_name not in class_names:
               class_names.append(class_name)
          classes.append(class_names.index(class_name))

    print "There are ",len(matches), " files're found!!"
    return matches, classes, class_names
```

However the problem here is, this function visits folders in a strange python order of the folder names. Instead I would like to traverse them through A-Z. How should I modify this code or use any other alternative to do this?

Comment: If you want more granular control (i.e. order matters), implement what you need yourself using e.g. [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the `topdown` parameter to `os.walk` is `True`, so a directory triplet is reported before its own directories are descended. [The docs state](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk):

> the caller can modify the `dirnames` list in-place (perhaps using `del` or slice assignment), and `walk()` will only recurse into the subdirectories whose names remain in `dirnames`; this can be used to prune the search, **impose a specific order of visiting,** or even to inform `walk()` about directories the caller creates or renames before it resumes `walk()` again.

Boldface mine. So all you need to do is something like:

```
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(root_path):
    dirnames[:] = natsort.natsorted(dirnames)
    # continue with other directory processing...
```

Since you need to edit the list in place, you need to use the `[:]` slice notation.

---

Here's an example of `os.walk`'s operation. Given a directory tree that looks like:

```
$ ls -RF cm3mm/SAM3/src
Applets/                RTC.cc          SAM3X/
DBGUWriteString.cc  SAM3A/          SMC.cc.in
EEFC.cc             SAM3N/          SoftBoot.cc
Memories.txt        SAM3S/
PIO.cc              SAM3U/

cm3mm/SAM3/src/Applets:
AppletAPI.cc   IntFlash.cc   Main.cc        MessageSink.cc  Runtime.cc

cm3mm/SAM3/src/SAM3A:
Map.txt     Pins.txt

cm3mm/SAM3/src/SAM3N:
Map.txt     Pins.txt

cm3mm/SAM3/src/SAM3S:
Map.txt     Pins.txt

cm3mm/SAM3/src/SAM3U:
Map.txt     Pins.txt

cm3mm/SAM3/src/SAM3X:
Map.txt     Pins.txt
```

Now, let's see what `os.walk` does:

```
>>> import os
>>> for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk("cm3mm/SAM3/src"):
...     print "-----"
...     print "root =", root
...     print "dirnames =", dirnames
...     print "filenames =", filenames
...
-----
root = cm3mm/SAM3/src
dirnames = ['Applets', 'SAM3A', 'SAM3N', 'SAM3S', 'SAM3U', 'SAM3X']
filenames = ['DBGUWriteString.cc', 'EEFC.cc', 'Memories.txt', 'PIO.cc', 'RTC.cc', 'SMC.cc.in', 'SoftBoot.cc']
-----
root = cm3mm/SAM3/src/Applets
dirnames = []
filenames = ['AppletAPI.cc', 'IntFlash.cc', 'Main.cc', 'MessageSink.cc', 'Runtime.cc']
-----
root = cm3mm/SAM3/src/SAM3A
dirnames = []
filenames = ['Map.txt', 'Pins.txt']
-----
root = cm3mm/SAM3/src/SAM3N
dirnames = []
filenames = ['Map.txt', 'Pins.txt']
-----
root = cm3mm/SAM3/src/SAM3S
dirnames = []
filenames = ['Map.txt', 'Pins.txt']
-----
root = cm3mm/SAM3/src/SAM3U
dirnames = []
filenames = ['Map.txt', 'Pins.txt']
-----
root = cm3mm/SAM3/src/SAM3X
dirnames = []
filenames = ['Map.txt', 'Pins.txt']
```

Each time through the loop, you get the directories and files for *one* directory. We know *exactly* which file belongs to which folder: the files in `filenames` belong to the folder `root`.

Comment: this would not work since filenames order now is not aligned with directory names.

Comment: Excuse me? You can sort the file names, too. What's the problem?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, in your approach you sort the folders but you miss the relative order of the fileas and the folders since at the end you dont know which file belongs to which folder. Right ?

Comment: Not at all! The callback is called *once* per folder, the one whose path is given in `root`. `dirnames` contains only the folders in `root`, and `filenames` contains only the files in `root`.

Answer (score -1):

I changed the code like this;

```
def get_data_paths(root_path, ext = '*.jpg'):
    import os
    import fnmatch
    import natsort  # import this
    matches = []
    classes = []
    class_names = []
    dir_list= natsort.natsorted(list(os.walk(root_path))) # add this
    for root, dirnames, filenames in dir_list:
      for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, ext):
          matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
          class_name =  os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(os.path.join(root, filename)))
          if class_name not in class_names:
               class_names.append(class_name)
          classes.append(class_names.index(class_name))

    print "There are ",len(matches), " files're found!!"
    return matches, classes, class_names
```